# Pandas, get all possible value combinations of length k grouped by feature

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe something like:

| Feature A | Feature B | Feature C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | C1 |
| A2 | B2 | C2 |

Given k as input, i want all values combination grouped by feature of length k, for example for k = 2 I want:

```
[{A:A1, B:B1},
 {A:A1, B:B2},
 {A:A1, C:C1},
 {A:A1, C:C2},
 {A:A2, B:B1},
 {A:A2, B:B2},
 {A:A2, C:C1},
 {A:A2, C:C2},
 {B:B1, C:C1},
 {B:B1, C:C2},
 {B:B2, C:C1},
 {B:B2, C:C2}]
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not that efficient but it works for small scale.

First, determine the unique combinations of `k` columns.

```py
from itertools import combinations
k = 2
cols = list(combinations(df.columns, k))
```

Then use `MultiIndex.from_product` to get cartesian product of `k` columns.

```py
result = []
for c in cols:
    result += pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df[x] for x in c]).values.tolist()
```

Comment: I forgot to put the key (column name) in final result.  let me know if that is required.

Comment: no thanks, I can do it by myself :). A small improvement, since the MultiIndex result has duplicates, it could be `pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df[x] for x in c]).unique().values`

Comment: Cool.  if that the case, would it be better to dedupe at df[x] level before passing to `from_product`?

Comment: Yes you're right, for efficiency purposes it would be better.